# A short book about a woman who helps defeat aliens that she had herself engineered in the future

Tags: story-identification, books

I read this book, a paperback, back in 2009 when I was homeless and a meth addict, so my memory of it is sketchy to say the least.

The protagonist is a young woman, given a mission to board a space ship, by a grim looking older woman. She succeeds to defeat alien monsters, and she also has a love interest involved. Then somehow it turns out in future that she herself engineers these creatures and populates their planet.

She ends up living somewhere in this ship or elsewhere off-world, my memory fails me here but I know she does not settle down with her love interest, and witnesses the end of the universe as well as the beginning of a new, identical one.

In the new universe she, in some sort of disguise, gives her younger self of the new universe the mission, so she becomes the miserable older woman. And finally she settles down with her love interest and lives out her days with him.

The only other details I recall is that the book was a quick read, it took only one or two hours, and I thought at the time it was not particularly well written, but I read it because my friend was raving about it.

Comment: Don't know if it helps but as far as I recall, the book was not so well written, but the premise and the plot was interesting.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: @Valorum Will do. Unfortunately I did read it at a bad time in my life and I don't think there's anything more I can remember. It was a paperback; don't recall the publisher or how old it was.

Comment: It reminds me of "Dark Future" by Klein, but that was published in 2011.

Comment: I skimmed Dark Future, and it does seem pretty similar to your description but [it was published in 2015](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/26595877-dark-future). Could you have got your dates mixed up? It's also a dreadful book, which also matches your description :-)

Comment: isfdb gives a publication date of 2011 for Dark Futures, which is slightly better, but still too late. I don't remember if the "lives out her days with her love interest" fits though, but I can confirm it is indeed a dreadful book.

Comment: Definitely didn't get my dates mixed up... I was homeless around six months in 2009 before going to rehab and relocating... And read it in those six months.

Comment: I'm going to have to skim Dark Future too. Could it have been a 2nd publishing or released under a different author's name?

Comment: Also I relocated from CT to Johannesburg after my stint in rehab, in early 2010, and had read the book some time the previous year for sure.

Comment: I seem to recall she settles down on some remote planet at the end, but my memory is too hazy.

Answer (score 5):

This sounds like [*The Starlight Crystal*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/137967.The_Starlight_Crystal) by Christopher Pike, published in 1995.

The actual plot of the book is considerably weirder and more complicated than your summary, but the details you mentioned do line up. From [a blog post that recaps the plot](https://littleapartmentbigcity.wordpress.com/2014/01/19/the-starlight-crystal-by-christopher-pike/):

> The book is about a girl who is the beginning and the end. She begins the book by meeting a young man named Tem only a week before she goes up into space and will remain there for 200 Earth years. ... So she goes up into space and while she’s up there, the planet gets destroyed and then the aliens come and take over her ship. Luckily, one of them is nice and sends her ship into what I guess you could consider “hyperdrive”, where they’re now traveling at an amazing speed and time is just passing ludicrously all around them. ...
>
> So as she’s alone on this ship, she watches the universe die and then gets reborn into the SAME EXACT UNIVERSE. ... So she lands on Earth the time that Tem was alive, meets and tries to kill her past self like she did before, and then waits for past self to leave before making a move on Tem. They get married and she ends up cloning them both, but they’re born as babies so Tem doesn’t know they’re clones.
>
> So they get up to the sky, and the main character kills Tem, reawakens her clone’s memories, creates the same aliens that destroyed Earth, then kills herself.

Comment: Interesting but no. I don't think so. The one I'm remembering definitely didn't involve clones and I think the aliens did destroy the planet and board the ship, and she did defeat them, only to later engineer them and I think, send them back in time. Don't remember the details there.

But she definitely didn't try to kill her ypounger self.